# Data service in roaming on blackberry phones

Tags: service, blackberry, roaming

Can I check in my application that data service is available in roaming? Can I use `PhoneState.isDataServiceAvailable()` for this situation or use another solution?

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with PhoneState. It doesn't seem to be part of the RIM API.

You can use RadioInfo.getNetworkService() and check that against the RadioInfo.NETWORK_SERVICE_ROAMING flag, that would tell you if you were roaming. Then you could check the RadioInfo.NETWORK_SERVICE_DATA flag to see if you had data.

But you want to know if it would be available, even if you're not currently roaming? There might be a service book for that, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks.
I think I use you method with RadioInfo.NETWORK_SERVICE_DATA. It should work in any cases(in roaming or in normal network)